# Is there a fix for more summary fields related contributions not populating on the related page if the related has no contributions

Tags: summaryfields

I know probably a convoluted question.

I love the related contributions in Joinery's More Summary Fields.  It solves the I want one combined contribution number for the HH and all it's members.  (This weakness with households and their related individuals in civicrm is driving my users to say let's dump civicrm.  Well, the whole manage households and their individuals is very painful to my users.)

The only problem is the related the related contact contribution and the Combined contact & related contact contributions is missing on some households and individuals which is horrible.  Incomplete data is a death knell.

It's missing where there are no contributions that the related contact has made.  So if you have a household that has never contributed anything and a household member that has, all the summary fields are missing on the household.

Comment: It's only the initial populating the table that doesn't work.  The triggers seem to work and create the record when a new contribution is added.  For the moment, I  queried up (with sql) all the ones that should have had a record and added a zero dollar donation.  That then fired the triggers and created the missing info.